# Prime and Maximal Ideals of $\mathbb{Z}[x]$ containing $(30,x^3+1)$

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, ideals, maximal-and-prime-ideals

What I've worked out so far is that $(30, x^3+1)$ is contained in $(2, x^3+1)$, $(3, x^3+1)$, and $(5, x^3+1)$.

For $(2, x^3+1)$, we have $\mathbb{Z}[x]/(2, x^3+1) \simeq \mathbb{F}_2[x]/(x^3+1)$. I notice that in $\mathbb{F}_2[x]$, we have $x^3+1 = (x+1)(x^2+x+1)$. So we can write a couple of the prime ideals in $\mathbb{Z}[x]$ as $(2, x^3+1, x+1)$ and $(2, x^3+1, x^2+x+1)$, which both clearly contain $(30, x^3+1)$ and quotient to $\mathbb{F}_2$ and $\mathbb{F}_4$, respectively. These are both fields, and hence domains, so those ideals are indeed prime and maximal.

I proceed with the same technique for the other ideals. Is this method correct in obtaining all the prime ideals? A second question is, will I ever get a non-maximal, prime ideal? It seems I only ever get maximal ideals because the quotients end up being fields.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct. To show that the primes obtained by your procedure exhaust all the ones containing $(30, x^3+1)$, you can use the fact that if $\mathfrak{p}\supset (30,x^3+1)$ then $30=2\times 3\times 5\in \mathfrak{p}$ and one of $2\in \mathfrak{p}, 3\in \mathfrak{p}, 5 \in \mathfrak{p}$ holds.

In fact, they are necessarily maximal. This is because they properly contain a nonzero principal prime ideal and the Krull dimension of $\mathbb{Z}[x]$ is equal to $2$.